# How to use srmklive/laravel-paypal v3 in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I'm using the srmklive/laravel-paypal v.3 package ( https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal that does not have documentation) in a laravel project.
Someone can explain me how to use it? And how can i set the request?

For example when i press a pay button the controller process this code:

```
public function payment()
{
    $provider = new PayPalClient;

    // Through facade. No need to import namespaces
    $provider = PayPal::setProvider();
    $provider->setCurrency('EUR');
    $provider->createOrder([
        "intent"=> "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units"=> [
            "amount"=> [
              "currency_code"=> "EUR",
              "value"=> "100.00"
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

But i have this error: **Trying to access array offset on value of type null**

Relative to this portion of code:

```
$this->apiUrl = collect([$this->config['api_url'], $this->apiEndPoint])->implode('/');
```

of class srmklive\paypal\src\Traits\PayPalAPI\Orders.php:21

This class is out of my controller because it's a library class, but there are no documentation.

Comment: Are you sure it works with L8? Readme doc mentions Laravel 5.1 to 5.8

Comment: i think yes, composer require srmklive/paypal:~2.0 for Laravel 5.1 to 5.8, composer require srmklive/paypal:~3.0 for others

Comment: config['api_url'] is null.
The class PayPal.php has setOptions($credentials) method that sets config['api_url']. This protected method is never called, is this a bug?

Comment: You should add info about these errors to your question instead of comment. I don't know this pkugin, however it seams like some config file is not filled. This method is a setter and *may be* called dynamicaly. BTW, README mentions "*After installation, you will need to add your paypal settings. Following is the code you will find in config/paypal.php, which you should update accordingly*" did you do that?

Comment: HI, did you find solution of this. If yes, then please post it as answer. I am also struggling hard to set paypal on Laravel 8. And all tutorials which I found are not working in laravel 8.  Please share detail solution if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to make it work. There's no documentation!

```
PayPal::setProvider();
$paypalProvider = PayPal::getProvider();
$paypalProvider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
$paypalProvider->setAccessToken($paypalProvider->getAccessToken());
```

Source
https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal/issues/407#issuecomment-798562911

Comment: I managed to complete the payment flow on paypal, but when the user is redirected to my site the paypal request  seems to have only two values: PayerID and Token. Where is the order ID? It does not seem to be there but I need it to recover the pending payment and place it in Paid/Completed.

Comment: $order =  $paypalProvider->createOrder(); just var_dump the order variable and you'll find the id there.  You either have to store that value in a session or database.

Comment: this line `PayPal::setProvider();` is giving error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PayPal' not found`. I am new in laravel. And struggling hard to get paypal done on laravel 8. Can you discribe what this line is about and why its showing error to me? ^^

Comment: Just add use PayPal; facade at the top of the file.